# How to persist a bundle with resources not still created on my fhir server?

Tags: hl7-fhir

In our CDA2FHIR mapping engine we are generating Fhir bundle from CDA document, but this Bundle has resources without real fhir IDs from our server. For example, one patient and another compartment objects like procedures, medicationPrescription, relatedPerson, ..... We need to persist this REsource network individually, but linked between them.

how should we created the Resources in the Bundle in the server? I think we should persist with certain sorting (first patient, practitioner, and relatedPErsons, and later rest of comparment resources). Is there some approach for this? some endpoint?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or guidance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Within a bundle, it's legitimate to give resources URNs rather than URLs.  I.e. urn:uuid:.... or urn:oid:....

This is covered in a single line in section 1.12.3.4.1: "Note that internal references are allowed to be URIs rather than literal URLs."

If you create multiple documents that reference the same Patient, Observation, etc., the uuid or OID used to identify that resource instance SHOULD be the same in each document you produce.